# Node JS problem Interacting with Ethereum Smart Contract

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, nodejs

I'm having only partial success with a `Node.js` script I wrote that interacts with one of my `Ethereum` Smart Contracts.

Here's what's working:
 
-I'm able to call methods in the Smart Contract *from* my `Node.js` script
-I'm able to capture and display the results returned from these function calls using my `Node.js` script

The problem I'm having has to do with capturing `EVENTS` that are emitted by the contract.

My code won't run cause I keep the following error:

`TypeError: theContract.saleTXReceivedEvent is not a function`

What's weird is the code I'm using in my `Node.js` file is the exact same code I've been using in my regular client-side JS files (which are embedded into my HTML files) - which work perfectly well.

Here's the code:

```
var capturedEvent = theContract.saleTXReceivedEvent();
capturedEvent.watch(function(error, result) {
  if(!error) {
    console.log("Sale was successful!");
    console.log("Results are as follows: ", result);
  }
  else {
    console.log("ERROR!!!! Details: ", error);
  }
});
```

So again, this code works perfectly in my client-side web files, but it gives me an error when in my node.js file:

`TypeError: theContract.saleTXReceivedEvent is not a function`

It is of course true that `saleTXReceivedEvent` is *not* a `Function` - its an `EVENT`, but in terms of the syntax, how else am I supposed to reference it? Why is it working fine in my regular JS files but failing in my `NodeJS` files?

What's going on here?

Comment: which version of web3 you are using?

Comment: I'm on version `1.2.4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

theContract.events.yourEventName is neccesary.

```
const theContract = new web3.eth.Contract(abi, contractAddress, {
    from: fromAddress,
    gasPrice: 200000000
});
theContract.events.saleTXReceivedEvent((error, event) => {
    console.log(event);
});
```

Comment: ok, that worked - but where is the `watch` portion of the code now? I originally assigned the Event to a variable called `capturedEvent`, and in the next statement did `capturedEvent.watch(function(error, result)  { }`  etc.  -  but your code doesn't have `watch` at all. How will that work then?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand probably older version syntax `.watch`.  Bellow @goodvibration's answer would help you.

Comment: Yep, I got it. `.watch` is used in `web3.js V. 0.x.x`, while in `V. 1.x.x` it is no longer needed.

Answer (score 0):

> What's weird is the code I'm using in my Node.js file is the exact same code I've been using in my regular client-side JS files (which are embedded into my HTML files) - which work perfectly well.

You clearly have two different versions of Web3.js installed:

- Your client-side environment relies on Web3.js v0.x.
- Your NodeJS environment probably relies on Web3.js v1.x.

---

Under Web3.js v0.x, you should use `theContract.saleTXReceivedEvent()`; see [this example](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#contract-events).

Under Web3.js v1.x, you should use `theContract.events.saleTXReceivedEvent()`; see [this example](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id38).

Comment: Hey @goodvibration you're right about how I'm using 2 different versions of `web3` - and about needing to add `.events` to my code for it to work. I'd mark yours as the correct answer but @engineerk provided that answer first. Really appreciate your contribution to this question though - I'm sure it'll be helfpul to future readers.